# @font-face не работает

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Добрый день друзья  возникла проблема  с работой  `@font-face` .Код раньше работал   а сейчас никак не отображается .Браузер  поддерживает   `@font-face` . формат `ttf`.Можете подсказать  проблему в коде.Заранее спасибо. 
Вот код

```
@font-face{
    font-family: CenturyGothic;
    src:url('font/CenturyGothic.ttf');
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;

}

*{
  font-family: CenturyGothic;
}
```

Comment: `url('../font/CenturyGothic.ttf');` - попробуйте так.

Comment: Спасибо @entithat  код сработал

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста)))

Answer (score 1):

Работающий код. Кому нибудь понадобится

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'CenturyGothic';
    src:url('../font/CenturyGothic.ttf');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;

}

*{
  font-family:'CenturyGothic',sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```